# C# Regex - only match if substring exists?

Tags: c#, regex, regex-lookarounds

Ok, so I think I've got a handle on negation - now what about only selecting a match that has a specified substring within it?

Given:

```
This is a random bit of information from 0 to 1.
  This is a non-random bit of information I do NOT want to match
This is the end of this bit

This is a random bit of information from 0 to 1.
  This is a random bit of information I do want to match
This is the end of this bit
```

And attempting the following regex:

```
/(?s)This is a random bit(?:(?=This is a random).)*?This is the end/g
```

Why isn't this working?  What am I missing?

I'm using regexstorm.com for testing...

Comment: What's expected result exactly?

Comment: Should select the entire 2nd block of text, and not the first.

What I'm looking to accomplish:

1) Determine a match based on a partial string of a line

2) Determine a match that ends with a partial string of a line

3) Capture based on some random string inside that start/end of a match.

Comment: Your example string is confusing, you should write a better one, shorter and more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You ruined a tempered greedy token by turning the negative lookahead into a positive one. It won't work that way because the positive lookahead requires the text to equal `This is a random`  at each position after `This is a random bit`.

You need:

- Match the leading delimiter (`This is a random bit`)
- Match all 0+ text that is not the leading/closing delimiters and not the required random text inside this block
- Match the specific string inside (`This is a random`)
- Match all 0+ text that is not the leading/closing delimiters
- Match the closing delimiter (`This is the end`)

So, use

```
(?s)This is a random bit(?:(?!This is a random bit|This is the end|This is a random).)*This is a random(?:(?!This is a random bit|This is the end).)*This is the end
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3Fs)This%20is%20a%20random%20bit(%3F%3A(%3F!This%20is%20a%20random%20bit%7CThis%20is%20a%20random%7CThis%20is%20the%20end).)*This%20is%20a%20random(%3F%3A(%3F!This%20is%20a%20random%20bit%7CThis%20is%20the%20end).)*This%20is%20the%20end&i=This%20is%20a%20random%20bit%20of%20information%20from%200%20to%201.%0D%0A%20%20This%20is%20a%20non-random%20bit%20of%20information%20I%20do%20NOT%20want%20to%20match%0D%0AThis%20is%20the%20end%20of%20this%20bit%0D%0A%0D%0AThis%20is%20a%20random%20bit%20of%20information%20from%200%20to%201.%0D%0A%20%20This%20is%20a%20random%20bit%20of%20information%20I%20do%20want%20to%20match%0D%0AThis%20is%20the%20end%20of%20this%20bit)

- `(?s)` - DOTALL mode on (`.` matches a newline)
- `This is a random bit` - Leading delimiter
- `(?:  # Start of the tempered greedy token
   (?!This is a random bit # Leading delimiter
      |
      This is the end      # Trailing delimiter
      |
      This is a random)    # Sepcific string inside
    .                      # Any character
   )*                      # End of tempered greedy token`
- `This is a random` - specified substring
- `(?:(?!This is a random bit|This is the end).)*` - Another tempered greedy token matching any text not leading/closing delimiters up to the first...
- `This is the end` - trailing delimiter

Comment: Wiktor, I'm gonna owe you a beer, sir.  That was a wonderful explanation - thank you!  I'll keep plugging away at this.  I'm bound to figure it out eventually, with helpful people like you on SO.

Comment: Glad to help.If it works for you please consider accepting.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you understand this `(?:(?=This is a random).)` can only match once, never twice if it were quantified. For example `Th` can satisfy the lookahead. When the `T` is consumed, the next character is `h` which will never satisfy the lookahhead `Th`. The next expression is evaluated, never to return to the lookahead again. Use a negative lookahead instead.